# Concurrency primitives: how to run a task only the latest time?

Tags: concurrency

Let me describe the problem:
`thread A` will want to tell `thread B` to do some work sometimes.
if `thread B` is currently doing work, it should do the new work when it finishes.
if `thread B` is currently doing work, and `thread A` tells `thread B` to do work 3 times, `thread B` should only do new work one time once it finishes

I believe this code solves the problem:

```
atomic_bool should_run = false

<Thread A> 
if (should start work) {
    should_run = true
}

<Thread B>
loop {
     if (should_run.compare_and_swap(true, false) {
          do_work()
     }
}
```

My question: how can I avoid a busy wait here?
In particular, an earlier idea was to do something like this:

```
<Thread A>
if (should start work) {
     notify(thread_b)
}

<Thread B>
loop {
     wait()
     do_work()
}
```

But this idea fails to the fact that if `thread B` is busy doing work, notifies from `thread A` can be missed entirely

Comment: Look up condition variables, which are designed to solve exactly this problem.  Pay attention in particular to how they are used in conjunction with mutexes.

Comment: The idea is that thread A should set the flag *and* notify.  And thread B should test the flag and *atomically* start to wait if it is false.  If new work arrives while B is already working, it will notice on the next iteration that the flag is set.  Otherwise, if B is not already working, then it must be waiting, and the notify will wake it up.  The atomicity ensures there is no gap between "working" and "waiting".

Comment: Thank you Nate. In the second example, I was using condition variables, but I didn't think to use both a condvar & a flag.